# Calculate force on atoms given the energy of configuration, trajectory of simulation and position of atoms in each frame

Tags: physical-chemistry, intermolecular-forces, molecular-dynamics

### Background

I am using a neural network to calculate the potential energy of atoms in a configuration and then adding energy of all atoms to compare it with the true energy of the configuration(label) to update the weights.

I am doing so for 10000 configurations of 100 atoms each for liquid Argon at 100K.

**Note** I don't have the actual energy of each atom and only the energy of the configuration.

### Problem

I need to calculate the forces on each atom to see if the sum of forces for all the atoms is zero in X,Y,Z axis. In case it is not I want to find out how off is it from zero.

How do I calculate the force on atoms using their position and potential energy for a given trajectory. I know I need to do $\frac{dE}{dr}$ but what should be my E and r. Also since I don,t a formula for E(r), what should my $dE$ and $dr$ be respectively?

Comment: I'm not sure this will be possible if you only know the energy of the configuration as a whole.

Comment: I would agree with a cyclohexane. I would imagine there would be any number of possible forces on each atom that would be consistent with a particular total energy.

Comment: @fireball.1 Actually, thinking about it more, this might be possible. I'm no expert on machine learning so correct if I'm wrong, but your network should take in the x,y,z coordinates of each atom in order to compute the energy. I believe a common feature in many machine learning libraries is the ability to compute derivatives with respect to an arbitrary input parameter. So, I would think it would be possible to obtain derivatives of the total energy with respect to the x,y,z coordinates of a given atom. This should give the force on the whole assembly of atoms.

Comment: @fireball.1 Possibly useful reference: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.05767.pdf

Comment: As a starting point why not use the Lennard-Jones 6-12 equation for Argon, the parameters for which  are known. This gives the energy vs r . You may need to include a long range potential additionally, as this potential is quite short range.

Comment: @porphyrin dude read the question properly. I'm using my own potential function in terms of the NN. I need the net force on system to check its accuracy. Involving LJ makes 0 sense

Comment: @a-cyclohexane-molecule is it at least possible to get the force on the whole system (as in 1 configuration) ?

Comment: @fireball.1, do you expect that there *is* a net force on the entire system? With regards to what you've posted in the comments, if you have a potential function, then surely you can differentiate that to get the force. I don't know how you can calculate the energy of your configuration without some sort of known potential function, but I also don't know much about neural networks either. I think porphyrin's suggestion is quite valid and would be my first choice for investigating such a system.

Comment: In addition, I'm not sure checking the accuracy of the potential function *by obtaining the force from the potential* is valid. You could check for self-consistency that way, but accuracy suggests that you need some other method for so doing.

Comment: @fireball.1 In regard to your comment to porphyrin: [be nice](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: @a-cyclohexane-molecule From what I do know about machine learning, he would have a potential function technically, the issue is that it is expressed in terms of the neural network (essentially a composition of a bunch of activator functions associated with given nodes). However, as I mentioned in my comment, I think its becoming more common for machine learning libraries to include derivatives wrt to the inputs, so even if he doesn't know the form of his potential, it should still be possible to obtain the derivatives.

Comment: @porphyrin sorry for my conduct. you were just trying to help

Comment: @a-cyclohexane-molecule so the NN acts like a black box potential function. And If using that potential i get that the net external force on the system is 0, that would mean my potential values are correct in that 1 aspect.

Comment: @Tyberius actually I cant't use that derivative thing because my actual input to the neural network is 2 symmetry functions using the x,z,y coordinates of atoms in my configuration. If I use the small change in energy between 2 configurations as $dE$ then what can i possibly use as my $dr$ ?

Comment: @fireball.1 are the symmetry functions differentiable with respect to the coordinates of a single atom?

Comment: symmetry function of each atom involves the position of atoms in vicinity too

Comment: apology accepted.

Answer (score 5):

## tl,dr: Forces are equivalent to the negative of the gradient, use small, arbitrary $\mathrm{d}r$ for each atom

The problem, as you mention, with many neural network methods in chemistry at the moment, is that the $E = f(x,y,z)$ is a black box and thus analytical gradients (and thus forces) are often not available.

First, as you clearly know, $F = -\nabla E(x,y,z)$ so you need to solve $\frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}r}$ for your neural network. (I indicate this for anyone reading who doesn't realize that the force will inherently be the negative of the gradient of the energy function.

So what you need is a finite difference method. This is, of course, a common problem (e.g., [on Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1713372/how-do-we-calculate-the-gradient-from-numerical-data) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation)):

$$ \frac{\partial E}{\partial x} \approx \frac{f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)}{\epsilon}$$

Picking a good step $\epsilon$ is a bit tricky, but I'd probably pick something like 0.01 Å or 0.001 Å, as a start. In your case, it sounds like you want Cartesian gradients, so you'll take your $f(x,y,z)$ and perform the partial derivatives for all three axes (i.e., the initial point $(x,y,z)$ plus 3 extra energy evaluations **per atom**.

That is, you'd loop through **each atom**, move it a bit in the x, y, and z directions and evaluate the system to get the gradient/force on that atom. You'll, therefore, have $3N$ energy evaluations to get all the forces on all the atoms.

You can perform better (and more computationally expensive) finite difference methods if you choose.

Comment: Since we are using a constant $\epsilon$ to calculate all forces, that means to calculate the total force i am just doing $f(x+n.\epsilon)-f(x)$ divided by $\epsilon$ and it's value doesn't really matter if the force on system is to be $0$.  Isn't this faulty in a way?

Comment: If you're *sure* that the forces are zero, then in principal $\epsilon$ doesn't matter. In practice, there are numerical issues that *do* matter, because forces are rarely exactly zero. Moreover, numerical accuracy issues often come into play.

Comment: Could you possibly point me to a more reliable reference for this kind of technique? It feels a little too easy you see 

Comment: @fireball.1 - this is a simple implementation of numerical gradients. If you don't trust me, you can see the links to [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1713372/how-do-we-calculate-the-gradient-from-numerical-data) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation)

Comment: @fireball.1 numerical differentiation is a very common technique, particularly in this type of case where it would it be difficult or impossible to compute an analytical derivative.

Comment: I'm fine with numerical differentiation. The constant $\epsilon$ is the only point I'm not so sure about.

Comment: I'm not sure your question - in any numerical derivative, you pick a small interval $\epsilon$. Picking one is dependent on your problem. Based on my experience, I made some suggestions in my answer.